# how to get value from json click event array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I have a list of data displayed from an API and when clicked shows relating data for example a list of authors which shows papers they have wrote once clicked. due to database restrictions I need to get the paper ID value from the paper that shows when an author is clicked.

does anybody know how to do this?
[data from fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM2DZ.png)

Paper.js

```
import React from "react";
import AuthorsNoClick from './authorsNoClick';


class Paper extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            display: false
        }
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({display:!this.state.display})
    }

    render() {
        let details ="";
        if (this.state.display){
            details = 
            <div>
                <p>Abstract</p>
                <p>{this.props.paper.abstract}</p>
                
                <AuthorsNoClick paperid={this.props.paper.paper_id}/>

                
            </div>
        } 
        return ( 
            <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
                <p>{this.props.paper.title}</p>
                {details}
            </div>
         );
    }
}
 
export default Paper;
```

AuthorNoClick.js

```
import React from "react";

class AuthorNoClick extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            display: false
        }
    }

    render() {

        

        return(
            <div>
            <p>{this.props.author.first_name + ' ' + this.props.author.last_name}</p>

            </div>
        )
    }   
}

export default AuthorNoClick;
```

AuthorsNoClick.js

```
import React from 'react';
import AuthorNoClick from './authorNoClick';


class AuthorsNoClick extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = { results : [] } // declaring state
        console.log("constructor");
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        let url = "http://localhost/api/authors";

        if (this.props.paperid !== undefined){
            url += "?paperid=" + this.props.paperid;
        } 
        
        
    
        
        fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
            
            if (response.status === 200) {
                return response.json() 
              } else {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
              }
        })
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({results:data})
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("something went wrong", err)
        })
        console.log("mounted")
    }
    render() {
        console.log("render");
        console.log(this.state.results);
        return (

            <div>       
                <p>Authors: </p>                                   
                {this.state.results.map( (author, i) => (<AuthorNoClick key={i} author={author} />) )}
            </div>
                
        )
    }
}
 
export default AuthorsNoClick;
```

papers.js

```
class Papers extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = { results : [] } // declaring state
        console.log("constructor");
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        let url = "http://localhost/api/papers";

        if (this.props.author_id !== undefined){
            url += "?authorid=" + this.props.author_id;
        }
 

        fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                return response.json() 
              } else {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
              }
            
        })
        .then((data) => {
            this.setState({results:data})
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("something went wrong", err)
        })
        console.log("mounted")
    }
    render() {
        console.log("render");
        console.log(this.state.results);
        
        return (
            
            <div>
                {this.state.results.map( (paper, i) => (<Paper key={i} paper={paper}/>) )}
            </div>
                
        )
    }
}
 
export default Papers;
```

Comment: just to confirm, you want to display only the data that matches the id that the user clicked? or do you want to display all the data in the component

Comment: just the data that matches the ID so for example a paper can have multiple authors. so once an author has been clicked it displays a paper I need that paper.id so I can then display other authors associated with the paper ID. at the minute I'm just displaying all the authors once clicked because I can't get any further than that. @DavidSalomon

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to achieve that, and there are several steps to do: (I will write functional components, but the logic is the same)

1. In the Author component add an id prop and in that way you will identify the component `<Author id={author.id}/>`
2. After fetching the whole list of authors, you need to create a click handler and a different state for the selected user

   ```
    const handleAuthor = (e) => { setSelectedAuthor(e.target.id)}
   ```
3. Once you have the id saved in the new state, you can use Array.filter() to display posts that only matches the id you have in the state

`authors.filter(author => author.id === selectedAuthor.id && <Author />)`